# How to achive Union All in pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have 3 data sets each having 415 GB of data and of different domain.

I need to union all of them using pig but all i can use it **union** clause which launches the reducers at the end of job to remove distinct values.

```
a = union a1, a2
data = union a, a3
```

Is there a way to skip the reducer part as the data is already distinct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs on [`UNION`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.1/basic.html#union):

> Use the UNION operator to merge the contents of two or more relations. 
>   The UNION operator:
>
> - Does not preserve the order of tuples. Both the input and output
>     relations are interpreted as unordered bags of tuples.
> - Does not ensure
>     (as databases do) that all tuples adhere to the same schema or that
>     they have the same number of fields. In a typical scenario, however,
>     this should be the case; therefore, it is the user's responsibility to
>     either (1) ensure that the tuples in the input relations have the same
>     schema or (2) be able to process varying tuples in the output
>     relation.
> - **Does not eliminate duplicate tuples.**

Emphasis is mine. This indicates to me there wouldn't need to be a reducer step to complete the `UNION` since it doesn't need to remove duplicate rows.  Are you sure that the reducer job is a result of the `UNION`?  It could be the result of another operator.

**BONUS:** You can simplify your example to:

```
B = UNION a1, a2, a3 ;
```

Comment: I am not sure but the script which i am running is only having union of three different files.